# How to read json file which have DBpedia labels stored in a list to extract the abstract for each label by using SPARQL in python

Tags: python, json, sparql, dbpedia, sparqlwrapper

I have a json file in which I have stored upto 300 DBpedia labels in a list. now I want to make a SPARQL query in python in a way that all of the labels are read through that file and print the abstract for each specific label present in the file instead of giving single DBpedia label in SPARQL query.
any help will be highly appreciated.
i have tried the below code which i am not sure about  that it is correct
code which i tried is given as follows
from rdflib import Graph
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper,JSON, N3
from pprint import pprint
import json
with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/dbpedia_lables.json', 'r') as f:
file = json.load(f)
def abstarctExtract(file):
sparql = SPARQLWrapper('http://dbpedia.org/sparql')
sparql.setQuery('''
SELECT ?label ?abstract
WHERE
{
{
:""" + file[1:-1] + """  rdfs:label ?label ;
dbo:abstract  ?abstract .

```
    }
```

''')

```
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
qres = sparql.query().convert()
for result in qres['results']['bindings']:
  lang, value = result['abstract']['xml:lang'],result['label']['xml:lang'], result['label']['value'], result['abstract']['value']
  if lang=='en':
    print(value)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what did you try? I mean, creating the SPARQL query string in Python and sending to DBpedia endpoint vai `sparqlwrapper` API isn't that difficult. I also suggest to create a single SPARQL query using `VALUES` clause

Comment: i edited my problem and added the code which i tried